# Nuxt 3: How to split a product list page (or similar) into numerous pages?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm following NetNinja's tutorial on how to fetch data from the [Fake Store API](https://fakestoreapi.com/) for a page that represents a product list, and then, with dynamic routing, create a new page for every product.

I'm trying to figure out how I can split the product list page into numerous pages because webshops typically don't display all their products on a single page. However, I can't determine the logic to achieve this. Should I create a new dynamic route for example, for every fourth products or should I fetch all the products in one page and split them in a another way?

View all products in the product list page:

> products/index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Products</p>
    <div v-for="p in products" :key="p.id">
      <NuxtLink :to="'/products/' + p.id">{{ p.title }}</NuxtLink>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const { data: products } = await useFetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products");
</script>
```

How to create a individual page for every product

> products/[uid].vue

```
<template>
    <p>Product details for {{ uid }}</p>
    <p> {{products.title}}</p>
</template>

<script setup>
const { uid } = useRoute().params

const { data: products } = await useFetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products/"+uid, { key: uid});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question. You want `products` page with pagination?